#  Cursor as an output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net, cursor

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 that returns a Cursor as an OUTPUT value. Is it possible to return this Cursor to a C# application using the .NET 4.0 framework?

My Stored procedure has the following signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
      @nuserid    int,
      @nfetchtype int,
      @returncursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS
...
```

At the end of the stored procedure I have

```
...
    set @returncursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC for SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE          column=@Value
    open @returncursor
END
```

In my C# Web Application, I use a wrapper that utilizes System.Data.DbType and I set my return value/parameter as DbType.Object. When I execute the query against the database, I get the following error:

> Operand type clash: sql_variant is incompatible with cursor

This DbType.Object parameter will work for a REFCURSOR in Oracle but I'm curious to see if there is a way to do the same for SqlServer. My goal is to have stored procedures in both SqlServer and Oracle that have the exact same signature.

Comment: Can you use the code option in the editor to format your SQL code? Also, is a cursor necessary here? They take up a large amount of resources and usually can be done with a restriction.

Comment: Why do you want to create a cursor ?

Comment: I want to create a cursor output value so I can have identical signatures between my Oracle and SqlServer stored procedures. With identical signatures, I can use the same method and parameter types for every stored procedure.

Comment: Why not use a `SqlDataReader` and drop the cursor altogether?

Comment: I suggest you stop wasting your time with cursors and rewrite your oracle sprocs to not use them. You'll probably hit all sorts for problems if you continue down this path.

Comment: Thanks mouters, can you hint at how I can rewrite my oracle sprocs to return datasets without the use of REF CURSORS? Seriously, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can have a CURSOR parameter in SQL, but ADO.NET can't use it. Instead, in .NET, you have to use the IDataReader returned by IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(), and use NextResult() to iterate over your result sets.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it seems limited that SQL Server will allow a CURSOR output from a stored procedure yet the .NET Framework can't handle it, although it can handle the Oracle REFCURSOR.

Comment: Actually, when I called Oracle SPs from .NET, I used MS' System.Data.OracleClient.dll (which is now deprecated) and it didn't support REFCURSOR properly either. I recall it generating some exceptions to the tune of "invalid SQL at level 0" when more than 1 REFCURSOR parameter was used.

Comment: I have no problems returning a REFCURSOR in Oracle to an output parameter with the OracleType.Cursor object from the System.Data.OracleClient library.
It seems impossible that .NET will allow this output from an Oracle product and not from SQL Server

Comment: Which client DLL did you use, ODP.NET or System.Data.OracleClient? How many REFCURSORs did you try passing? As I said, I had problems with 2 or more; 1 worked just fine for me.

Comment: I only returned 1 REFCURSOR per procedure, also no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use cursors in database APIs such as OLE DB, ODBC, ADO, and DB-Library etc.

Please go through [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) before using the cursors.